When did St Peter receive the Keys of Heaven?
We read in Matt 16: 18-19 ( NIV):

And I tell you that you are Peter, and on this rock I will build my church, and the gates of Hades will not overcome it.
I will give you the keys of the kingdom of heaven; whatever you bind on earth will be bound in heaven, and whatever you loose on earth will be loosed in heaven.”.

We believe that Christ opened the Gates of Heaven with his redemptive mission. Events of Mtt 16 take place  before the Passion. Later, in John 21:15-17   we see Jesus, after his Resurrection,  asking Peter to profess his love and gives him authority as shepherd of his flock.
Many scholars believe that the Keys of Heaven were given to Peter at the event described in Matthew 16. But a doubt arises  as to how the Keys could be  handed over even before the Gates of Heaven were opened at the death and resurrection of Jesus. My question therefore is: When did St Peter receive the Keys of Heaven ?

Just asking why the phrase Jesus used, 'the keys of the kingdom of heaven," has been truncated to 'the keys of heaven'? This seems to switch the sense to entrance into a place (heaven, and happening after death) when this kingdom is a realm into which all believers gain entrance at their confession of Christ; the same one Peter made in v.16. They do not have to die physically. This entrance happens through confession of faith in the Christ, the Son of the living God, surely? Thus I cannot answer this Q as it is based on a view opposite to what I hold.

It is important to note that the key mentioned in Matthew 16:19 is not a physical key for opening door. Instead, it symbolizes the transfer of authority and delegation.
A prophecy given to Isaiah, recorded in Isaiah 22:22, states:

I will place on his shoulder the key to the house of David; what he opens no one can shut, and what he shuts no one can open.

The prophecy is fulfilled in Jesus, who holds the authority who can enter the kingdom of heaven. It should be understood that Jesus does not literally stand by the door to check each person's entry ticket. Matthew 16:18-19 states:

18 And I tell you that you are Peter, and on this rock I will build my church, and the gates of Hades will not overcome it. 19 I will give you the keys of the kingdom of heaven; whatever you bind on earth will be bound in heaven, and whatever you loose on earth will be loosed in heaven.”

The term "this rock" refers to the cornerstone of Jesus' church, which is Jesus Himself. The term "it" refer to the Church, which Satan can never overcome. Therefore the keys of the kingdom of heaven resides with the Church, to which Jesus delegated power and authority after His ascension.
The key is not given to Peter alone, but to the Church. Peter and other disciples carried on the Commission to "make disciples of all nations, baptizing them in the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit, and teaching them to obey everything I have commanded you." (Matthew 28:19-20). Jesus has the authority to give this delegation, for “All authority in heaven and on earth has been given to Him." (Matthew 28:18).
Conclusion
The Keys of Heaven refer to the Church of Jesus, to which Peter and the disciples were delegated to carry on the Commission before Jesus ascension.

"The term "this rock" refers to the cornerstone of Jesus' church, which is Jesus Himself." — Yes.
Notice that in Matthew 16:18 the words "Peter" and "rock" that Jesus puns on, are two similar but different Greek words.
1 Corinthians 10:4 uses G4073 (petra) to twice refer to Jesus,
but throughout scripture G4074 (petros) is used only for Peter's nickname ("Rocky", "Pebble", "Stony"?).
Jesus is contrasting Peter and Christ, not equating the two words.

Christ came preaching that the kingdom of heaven was at hand in the 1st century AD during his 3-1/2 year ministry on earth.

From that time Jesus began to preach, and to say, Repent: for the kingdom of heaven is at hand. (Matt. 4:17, KJV)


And saying, The time is fulfilled, and the kingdom of God is at hand: repent ye, and believe the gospel. (Mark 1:15, KJV)

Jesus instructed His disciples to do the same as He sent them out to the other cities.

And as ye go, preach, saying, The kingdom of heaven is at hand. (Matt. 10:7, KJV)

Then, what is the kingdom of God?  It is the everlasting kingdom over which Christ rules from the right hand of the Father, the spiritual kingdom that is not of this earth, but is possessed by all the saints who are in Christ.

Neither shall they say, Lo here! or, lo there! for, behold, the kingdom of God is within you. (Luke 17:21, KJV)

Prophesied to be established in the days of the fourth beast which Daniel described, and which began with Babylon, then the Medo-Persian rule, followed by the Greek rule, and finally the ancient Roman empire.  It was during those days of the Roman empire that the spiritual kingdom under the gospel of Christ was established, and His reign is forever and ever.  (Dan.2:31-44; 7:3-27)
Keys open doors, or treasure chests, or store chests of great value.  Peter opened the door of the kingdom of heaven to the Jews on the day of Pentecost in Acts 2.

36 Therefore let all the house of Israel know assuredly, that God hath made the same Jesus, whom ye have crucified, both Lord and Christ.


37 Now when they heard this, they were pricked in their heart, and said unto Peter and to the rest of the apostles, Men and brethren, what shall we do?


38 Then Peter said unto them, Repent, and be baptized every one of you in the name of Jesus Christ for the remission of sins, and ye shall receive the gift of the Holy Ghost. (Acts 2:36-38, KJV)

And, Peter opened the door to the kingdom of heaven for the gentiles at the house of Cornelius in Acts 10.

47 Can any man forbid water, that these should not be baptized, which have received the Holy Ghost as well as we? 48 And he commanded them to be baptized in the name of the Lord. Then prayed they him to tarry certain days. (Acts 10:47-48, KJV)

They were not literal keys, but the emblem, the symbol of the birth of the church at Jerusalem, spreading out into all of the surrounding areas until the gentiles were grafted in. We knock on that door and ask for entrance when we are baptized in Christ. (Matt. 7:7-8; Luke 11:9-10; Rev. 3:20).
But, the church which is the spiritual kingdom of God that is not of this world (John 18:36) was opened first at Jerusalem in Acts 2 approx. AD 30-31, and then at the house of Cornelius by Peter about 9-10 years after Pentecost.

Peter received nothing more than other apostles; when Lord promises Peter that He will give him the keys to heaven, it is the same “key”, that is to say the same grace of Holy Spirit and authority of forgiving sins, which He gave to all other apostles and through which they can bind or unbind things on earth (Matthew 18:18-20 /note that δήσητε and λύσητε here is in plural, addressed to all apostles/; John 20:23), for to open the gate of paradise is nothing else semantically than absolving one from sins and no apostle had this authority in any lesser manner than Peter.
Thus, Peter received “keys” with all other apostles with the gift of Holy Spirit of absolving the sins as said by John (John 2:23).

Are the other apostles described as “receiving the keys of heaven”? Otherwise this appears to be eisegesis

@AviAvraham "Key to heaven" is something that opens heaven; that something is absolution of sins; this was received by all apostles likewise. That Peter was said to receive the keys does not mean that other disciples were excluded at all. Moreover, if you agree that "key" is a metaphor for the authority of absolving the sin (and I see no reason for why you or anybody would disagree), then we can say by 100% assuredness that also other apostles were give the same keys. On the contrary, saying that only Peter was given it exclusively is a gross eisegesis given what was said here above.

Perhaps include an explicit quotation of Matthew 18:18, which has an almost identical wording, but uses "ye" (plural, Disciples) rather than "thou" (singular, Peter). KJV Search Results for "bind" AND "on" AND "earth".

@RayButterworth Thanks, have done it.
